# How to process the same message sequentially in Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Camel and I am trying to do the following.

I want to process the same message twice. I have to transform both messages and process one message first and then second only if the first one is sucessfully executed (I have a condition).

I tried to use a multicast first. Then I transform the messages in each route. The first one (the operation_DC) only sends a successfull message to the second one (the operation_AC) only if it is sucessfull. The second operation contains an aggregation that waits until it times out for both messages. I only want to process the messaged from the multicast and discard the other.

```
<route id="t_operation_ME">
    <from uri="direct:operation_ME" id="t.direct.aggregatedService"></from>
    <setHeader headerName="id">
        <simple>exchangeId</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <multicast parallelProcessing="true" strategyRef="defaultAggregationStrategy" stopOnException="true" onPrepareRef="cleanHeader" parallelAggregate="false" completionPredicate="">
        <to uri="direct:operation_DC"></to>
        <to uri="direct:operation_AC"></to>
    </multicast>
</route>

<route id="direct:operation_DC">
    <from uri="direct:operation_DC" />
    <log message="ENTER DC"></log>
    <to uri="xslt:{{depasse:core.transformation.xml.path}}client/t/Operation_toDC_request.xsl" id="t.dc.transform.productos" />
    <to uri="activemq:QCIn" id="t.dc.qcin.queue.send"></to>
    <log message="EXIT DC ${body}"></log>
    <choice>
        <when>
            <xpath>//Data/Status[. = 'OK']</xpath>
            <log message="SEND TO AC"></log>
            <to uri="direct:operation_AC"></to>
        </when>
    </choice>
</route>

<route id="direct:operation_AC">
    <from uri="direct:operation_AC" />
    <log message="ENTER AC"></log>
    <aggregate completionTimeout="20000" completionSize="2" discardOnCompletionTimeout="true" strategyRef="tAggregationStrategy">
        <correlationExpression>
            <simple>header.id</simple>
        </correlationExpression>
        <log message="ENTER AGG AC ${body}"></log>

        <to uri="xslt:{{depasse:core.transformation.xml.path}}client/t/Operation_toAC_request.xsl" id="t.ac.transform.productos" />
        <to uri="activemq:QCIn" id="t.ac.qcin.queue.send"></to>
        <log message="EXIT AC ${body}"></log>
    </aggregate>
    <log message="END AC\n${body}"></log>
</route>
```

The thing is that when I log "EXIT AC" and "END AC" the message is different. This means that while in the server I am watching the process correctly, the AC client receives an incorrect message.

Comment: The route id is operationCDI_AC not operation_AC. Is that correct?

Comment: You are right cris. But I changed all the names in order to publish the question here in StackOverflow. I edited the question and you should see it as plainly as "operation_AC".

Answer (score 0):

Multicast send copy of messages always to every endpoint between  tags. If you want to call route operation_AC only after operation_DC run successfully, you shouldn't use multicast, but you should save your body at the beginning of operation_DC, for example using property and [Camel Simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html):

```
<from uri="direct:operation_DC" />
<setProperty propertyName="body">
    <simple>${body}</simple>
</setProperty>
```

and before calling operation_AC set body to bring message body from the beginning:

```
<setBody>
    <simple>${property.body}</simple>
</setBody>
<to uri="direct:operation_AC"/>
```